# SSIS - How to deal with Nested Set struct to build a dimention table?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssas, nested-sets

I'm working on a SSIS project in order to build a datawarehouse (SQL Server 2012).

Using PARENT_ID field to manage parent/child relationship is easy to store in a dimension table and automatically recognized by SSAS when designing a hierarchy structure.

In my project, I need to design a Location dimention based on a Nested Set structure.

[image]

What is the best way to store Locations in my dimention table by keeping a star schema ?
How to configure my dimention in my SSAS project to be able to browse the tree structure (I don't know the depth).

Should I store these data as a Nested Set then dealing with SSAS ?
How to map Nested Set with a hierarchy structure ?

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) is a doc about Nested Set.

Thanks !

Comment: https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330 Adventure Works has some examples with hierarchies download AdventureWorks Multidimensional Models SQL Server 2012

Comment: There is no Nested Set structure in AdventureWorks data source.

Comment: exactly, there is no nested structure in SSAS. There is hierarchies , you should (if this possible) look in AW2012 dimensions where is hierarchies and make your dimension table like in AW2012...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree structures based on `parent_id` seems to be the only supported way to deal with SSAS.

As suggested, I added a `parent_id` field to my table. One of my SSIS package loads data in the table, then another package focuses on the tree migration by populating the `parent_id` field after querying the parent element (by using the `left`, `right` fields).

To get something more efficient I added another field to track changes.

So, my table contains 4 fields (`parent_id`, `left`, `right` and `is_outdated`).